# How to match clientWidth in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I can't find a way to get the same width using jQuery as I do with vanilla javascript.

I need to use jQuery, but the value that I need is `577px` to be correct, which I'm only getting with vanilla js

```
document.getElementById('status_across_leagues').clientWidth  // returns 577

$('#status_across_leagues').width(); // returns 568

$('#status_across_leagues').innerWidth() // returns 588

$('#status_across_leagues').outerWidth() // returns 588
```

Comment: did you try `getBoundingRect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be mindful of padding and the presence of a scrollbar since these functions behave differently:

| function | ignores padding | ignores scrollbar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `.width()` | yes | no |
| `.innerWidth()`/`.outerWidth()` | no | yes |
| `.clientWidth` | no | no |

Therefore, [`Element.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) will not match the behavior of any of those functions. If you need the exact number and *must* use jQuery, then you can just use `$(el).prop('clientWidth')`. See demo below.

```js
function info(el) {
  const $el = $(el);
  $el.next().html(
    ' clientWidth: ' + el.clientWidth +
    ' | width(): ' + $el.width() +
    ' | innerWidth(): ' + $el.innerWidth() +
    ' | outerWidth(): ' + $el.outerWidth(true) +
    ' | prop(): ' + $el.prop('clientWidth')
  )
}
$('div').each((i, el) => info(el))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="aDiv" style="width: 200px;">no padding, no scroll</div><pre></pre>
<div id="bDiv" style="padding: 5px; width: 200px;">padding only</div><pre></pre>
<div id="cDiv" style="overflow-y: scroll; width: 200px;">scroll only</div><pre></pre>
<div id="dDiv" style="padding: 5px; overflow-y: scroll; width: 200px;">padding and scroll</div><pre></pre>
```